# Unrecognized field at: "database.flyway" in Dropwizard application with flyway bundle

Tags: java, maven, flyway, dropwizard

I'm working in a dropwizard application with a config.yml of

```yaml
database:
  driverClass: org.postgresql.Driver
  user: ...
  password: ...
  url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
  properties:
    charSet: UTF-8
    hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
  flyway:
    enabled: true
    locations:
      - "classpath:db/migration"
```

My dropwizard Application class's `run()` method looks like

```java
    @Override
    public void run(WebConfiguration webConfiguration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
        DataSource dataSource = webConfiguration.getDatabase().build(environment.metrics(), "database");

        Flyway flyway = webConfiguration.getFlywayBundle().getFlywayFactory(webConfiguration).build(dataSource);
        flyway.migrate();

    }
```

And my `WebConfiguration.java` class looks like

```java
public class WebConfiguration extends Configuration {
    @Valid
    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty
    // configures the application's database connection.
    public DataSourceFactory database = new DataSourceFactory();
    public DataSourceFactory getDatabase() {  return database;}

    public void setDatabase(DataSourceFactory database) {
        this.database = database;
    }

    public FlywayBundle<WebConfiguration> getFlywayBundle() {
        return new FlywayBundle<WebConfiguration>() {
            @Override
            public PooledDataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory(WebConfiguration webConfiguration) {
               return webConfiguration.getDatabase();
            }
        };
    }

}
```

I've installed the `dropwizard-flyway` module in my `pom.xml`:

```xml
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    <version>9.16.3</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>io.dropwizard.modules</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard-flyway</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-1</version>
 </dependency>
```

When I compile the application using `mvn package` and run the jar using the `config.yml` file, I get this error:

```bash
! at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:94)
! at com.dexcane.server.MyApplication.main(MyApplication.java:27)
io.dropwizard.configuration.ConfigurationParsingException: src/main/resources/config.yml has an error:
  * Unrecognized field at: database.flyway
    Did you mean?:
      - user
      - url
      - maxSize
      - password
      - minSize
        [33 more]

    at io.dropwizard.configuration.ConfigurationParsingException$Builder.build(ConfigurationParsingException.java:277)
    at io.dropwizard.configuration.BaseConfigurationFactory.build(BaseConfigurationFactory.java:161)
    at io.dropwizard.configuration.BaseConfigurationFactory.build(BaseConfigurationFactory.java:94)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.parseConfiguration(ConfiguredCommand.java:139)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:85)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:78)
    at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:94)
    at com.dexcane.server.MyApplication.main(MyApplication.java:27)
```

I thought the `dropwizard-flyway` bundle would enable my application to recognize the flyway field in my configuration?